# Is it possible to browse HSTS sites over SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: tls, proxy, chrome, hsts, socks5

I am unable to browse HSTS websites using SOCKS5 proxy in chrome browser...getting this error...

> This site can’t be reached The web page at
>    https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=en might be temporarily down or
>   it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED

[image: debug console]

Comment: That doesn't look like an HSTS error. Have you tried browsing to other sites?

Comment: yes ..... https://google.com works fine ... facebook not working..check the debug console.

Comment: The debug console does not appear to show any errors or things that would help with troubleshooting. Those are just headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOCKS5 by itself just make sure that the necessary TCP connectivity to the target is created and that all data are forwarded between client and server. It also might do a DNS lookup to resolve the hostname. A plain SOCKS5 proxy does not change anything with the payloads or changes the requested target server which means that HSTS will continue to work the same as without proxy.

But what you see here as error has nothing to do with HSTS at all.  `ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED` means that the SOCKS5 server was unable to create a connection to the requested target. This is a problem creating the TCP  connection already and has nothing to do with HTTPS and thus also not with HSTS.

Comment: Agreed.  It’s likely OP SOCKS proxy has been turned off and they need to start it before trying again.

Comment: I found that proxy server is blocking social sites in /etc/hosts file...thanks for your replies....